# Processing of non-existent collection fields in SonataAdminBundle forms

Tags: php, json, forms, collections, sonata-admin

I have an entity class ContactsPage to store some information about emails, phones etc. The problem is to get all this information into one field "contacts" in json-format defined within the ContactsPage entity:

```
class ContactsPage
{
...
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contacts", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $contacts;
...
}
```

ContactsPageAdmin form constructing example for emails:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('emails', 'collection', 
              array(
                  'mapped' => false, 
                  'required' => false,
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'allow_add' => true,
                  'allow_delete' => true,
              )
         );
}
```

- How and where can I get this "emails" array (or collection)?
- Where can I handle this array to make json and push it into "contacts" field before saving the ContactsPage entity?
- Where and how I can handle "contacts" field and transfer all decoded from json information into editing form (into "emails" collection)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spent almost the day but found answers by myself.
First and second questions.
I have to define prePersist and preUpdate methods within the admin-class with my Entity as an argument, where i can get and handle "emails" array:

```
class ContactsPageAdmin extends Admin
{
...
    public function prePersist($contactsPage)
    {
        $emails = $this->getForm()->get('emails')->getData();
        $contactsPage->setContacts(json_encode($emails));
    }
    public function Update($contactsPage)
    {
        $emails = $this->getForm()->get('emails')->getData();
        $contactsPage->setContacts(json_encode($emails));
    }
...
}
```

What about third question. I just have to use $this->getSubject() to get original Entity and 'data' property to load needed data:

```
class ContactsPageAdmin extends Admin
{
...
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        $entity = $this->getSubject();           // getting original Entity
        $json = $entity->getContacts();          // field with json data
        $array = json_decode($json, true);

        // preparing data to fulfill necessary form fields
        $array['emails'] = is_array($array['emails']) ? $array['emails'] : array();

        $formMapper
            ->add('emails', 'collection', 
                array(
                    'mapped' => false, 
                    'required' => false,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'data' => $array['emails']    //  embeding prepared data into collection
                )
              );
    }
...
}
```